# Conditional probability puzzle

Tags: probability

A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there is equal evidence against both of them. In further investigation at the crime scene, it is found that the guilty party had a blood type found in 10% of the population. Suspect A does match this blood type, whereas the blood type of Suspect B is unknown.

Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty party?

So here is my approach.
 Let A stands for "A gulity", M for "A matching the blood type" and N for "B matching the blood type". Then,
P(A) = P(B) = $\frac{1}{2}$
P(M) = $1$ 
P(N) = $\frac{1}{10}$

$P(A|M)=\frac{P(M|A)P(A)}{P(M)}$
$P(A|M)=\frac{1.\frac{1}{2}}{1}$
$=\frac{1}{2}$

The answer is given as $\frac{10}{11}$. More than arriving at this answer I am keen to understand what am I missing here.

Comment: You haven’t used $P(N)$ at all. How did you come up with $P(M\mid A)=1$?

Comment: $P(M|A)$ is "A matching the blood type" given "A is guilty". The two are independent events so $P(M|A) = P(M)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes with your $M$ and $N$ events. Suppose we have the next events:

Event $A$ for A is guilty.

Event $B$ for B is guilty.

Event $F$ for blood type is found in the crime scene.

As you have stated, we have first:
$$ P(A) = P(B) = 1/2$$
We also have:
$$ P(F \vert A) = 1$$
$$ P(F \vert B) = 1/10$$
Which leads to:
$$P(F) = P(F \vert A) P(A) + P(F \vert B) P(B) = 11/20$$
And by Bayes:
$$ P(A \vert F) = \frac{P(F \vert A) P(A)}{P(F)} = 10/11$$

Comment: Isn't P(F) = 1? Because blood type is found for sure. Also whether A is guilty or not his blood type matches guilty type.

Comment: P(F) is the probability of finding blood type, considering that only A and B can be guilty, not conditioned to any evidence. In P(A|F) is where you are taking into account the evidence that you have

Comment: @Gerry See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4215193.